# Live Log Viewer in django

Tags: jquery, django

I am newbie to web development and DJango. I would like to develop a live log viewer somthing like tail -f in the web. This is going to be part of a big internal project. Can someone give me some idea on how i should start on this?

My idea on how this should look is to have two drop down list. One for directories and once you choose the directories the second will list the logfiles in it. The selected logfile should open in a tab and show running log file.

How can i give access to those log directories in Django?
Do we have any tab control in DJango to open up files in new tabs? If not i am looking for a closable button tabs, how should i do this? What is the best way of reading logfiles and showing it on web page.

Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) and be extremely paranoid about user inputs.

Comment: No, you shouldn't do that by running "tail -f" with subprocess. Bad, bad idea.

Comment: There's definitely no reason to do so - you can easily implement tail with native python code. Running "tail -f" on Django view and returning the results (probably by polling with ajax) is not efficient at all (forking new processes). As an answer to question, probably reading new data from log once every few seconds or so is much better (f=open(filename), f.seek(int(request.GET.get("lastlocation", 0))), return HttpResponse(...f.read())). How you are going to terminate "tail -f" when user closes the browser?

Comment: Was this ever implemented? I have the same question, I have my tail -f function working, but can't put the new lines into Textarea field from django. `response = HttpResponse(follow(logFile))  return response`works, but how to i put this response to my `LogForm`